# Do i have to define every controller method in routes.php?

Tags: laravel, routes

This is my current routes.php file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/posts','PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create','PostsController@create');
Route::get('/tags','TagsController@index');
Route::get('/health','HealthController@index');
Route::get('/health/create','HealthController@create');
Route::get('/health/categories','HealthController@categories');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
```

If i dont do that for exmaple, i canbt use helpers in blade views , like action. It throws a null exception.

So the question is, do i have to define here all the controller actions? Or else i will not be able to use them directly? For example in a redirect to action link.

Adding this to blade:

```
<a href="{{ action('PostsController@index') }}">
```

throws an exception UNLESS i specifically add the route with Route::get NOT working if i add an entry to Route::controllers.

Tried also

```
<a href="{{ action('\App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@getIndex') }}">
<a href="{{ action('\App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index') }}">
```

Comment: Actually you should be able to. Please show the code that throws the exception and the error message itself

Comment: You need to define either a `controller` route - or individual routes. This blog is relevant: https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here are your controller action names. If you use implicit controller routes (`Route::controllers`) your method names have to **start with an HTTP verb**.

Instead of `index()` you need `getIndex()`.

You can easily check what routes Laravel actually registers using the `php artisan route:list` command.

Generating an URL would then look like this:

```
<a href="{{ action('PostsController@getIndex') }}">
```

---

**Note** Controller routing only works if you add `PostsController` to the `Route::controllers`. (I assumed you did so but just to be sure)

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    'posts' => `PostsController`
]);
```

Comment: FYI - he isnt actually registering the `PostsController` in his routes. He is wondering if it is more like Codeigniter where there is automatic controller route mapping (where there obviously isnt)

Comment: I don't think so: *"throws an exception UNLESS i specifically add the route with Route::get NOT working if i add an entry to Route::controllers."*. But anyways, I'll add a note to my answer..

Comment: Yeah - he is saying is there a way he doesnt have to specifically add it? At least that is what I think he is asking

Comment: Either way your answer is correct - so +1 from me :)

Comment: I think he's asking for a way where he doesn't have to specify every action with `Route::get()`... Thanks ;)

Comment: boith are correct.Yes i did add the postscontroller properly, BUT i did not followed the naming convention..So everything must be defined iunless i use controllers which as i see is discouraged in laravel documentation

Comment: @e4rthdog The documentation doesn't discourage using implicit controller routes, Phil Sturgeon does ;)